# when create new laravel project this is appear

Tags: php, laravel

This appears

[image]

What should I do and what

this is installed.json in compser file

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "psr/container": "^1.0"
    },
```

and this is composer.json in laravel file 
`"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "doctrine/inflector": "~1.0",
        "erusev/parsedown": "~1.6",
        "league/flysystem": "~1.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "~1.11",
        "mtdowling/cron-expression": "~1.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "~1.20",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "~1.4|~2.0",
        "ramsey/uuid": "~3.0",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.4",
        "symfony/console": "~3.2",
        "symfony/debug": "~3.2",
        "symfony/finder": "~3.2",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "~3.2",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "~3.2",
        "symfony/process": "~3.2",
        "symfony/routing": "~3.2",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "~3.2",
        "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "~2.2",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2"
    },`
please help me

Comment: I put a picture but I do not know where I went

Comment: Upgrade you PHP TO 5.6 or greater `"php": ">=5.6",`

Comment: How do I install a newer version from wamp server?

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer are you running